# NSTextView won't support redo and undo in Cocoa app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I searched this topic and never was able to find any answers to this.
When I make a new project in Xcode and I place a NSTextView as part of an
NSScrollView in my app, everything works fine as it should. The only thing is undo and redo won't work. It just does the funk noise

Copy, Cut, Paste all work as expected tho.

I get the same result if I do an app from scratch (no Storyboard) and code it in. Still undo and redo doesn't work?

Anyone knows what is the deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Cocoa app project that doesn't use the document architecture and add a text view, the text view does not allow undo initially.

[image]

Select the Allows Undo checkbox in the attributes inspector to turn on undo support.

One more thing. When you add a text view to a storyboard or xib file, the text view includes its own scroll view. You don't have to place the text view inside a scroll view.